# Error regarding Bluetooth module

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to work with a Bluetooth module (connected to a Uno board) via an Android app, and I haven't been successful. However the LED connected can be turned on using the app via bluetooth but it cannot be turned off. Code uploading was successful. But the bar at the bottom indicates an error as follows.

> avrdude:stk500_recv ():programmer is not responding

Do I need to make some updates or download some libraries? And how can I fix this to turn off the LED?

When the code was uploaded again the error wasn't indicated at the bottom. But still it works to turn on but not to turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How did you upload the sketch? With the Bluetooth module still connected? In that case please disconnect it and the upload. Connect again after the upload. – Mikael Patel Jan 16 '16 at 11:35

[Look here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19626/bluetooth-module-with-stk500-recv-error)